# Cannot connect my phone: `mtpfs` command and `modprobe fuse` command fail

Tags: gentoo, fuse, modprobe, mtp

I am trying to connect my phone in `Gentoo`. I have `mtpfs` installed and `FUSE` enabled in my kernel, `user_allow_other` set in `/etc/fuse.conf`. I ran `modprobe fuse` with and without `-fv` flags and it produces no output on the console. But my device is detected but when I ran `mtpfs /path/to/mount/my/phone` it just asks to run `modprobe fuse` again. I tried restarting but it didn't help. USB debugging is enabled and I have File Transfer selected. I tried running directly as root  (`su`) with `-o allow_other`

#### Specifications

```ruby
OS: Gentoo Linux x86-64
Host: VirtualBox 1.2
Kernel: 5.10.76-gentoo-r1
DE: Plasma 5.22.5
WM: KWin
GPU: VirtualBox Graphics Adapter
```

[Note: Language for above specifications is given as `Ruby` for the sole purpose of highlighting. It is obviously not `Ruby`]

`fusermount -V` gives the version as `2.9.9`

#### Error

```
mtpfs Devices/Android/
Listing raw device(s)
Device 0 (VID=2717 and PID=ff48) is a Xiaomi Mi-2s (MTP).
   Found 1 device(s):
   Xiaomi: Mi-2s (MTP) (2717:ff48) @ bus 1, dev 5
Attempting to connect device
Android device detected, assigning default bug flags
Listing File Information on Device with name: 
fuse: device not found, try 'modprobe fuse' first
```

`modprobe fuse`produces no output. I tried running this as root several times. But the same error is thrown again and again.

`modprobe -V` gives the following

```
kmod version 29
-ZSTD +XZ +ZLIB -LIBCRYPTO -EXPERIMENTAL
```